# How to associate "missed_days" with a date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

A user has many good habits. If one day he misses doing his habit then he is suppose to click here:

**habits/_habit.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to new_habit_level_days_missed_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: habit.current_habit_level.id }), id: 'remove_check' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
<% end %>
```

[image]

He is then redirected to:

**views/days_missed/new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@habit) do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :missed_days_date %>
  <%= link_to 'Submit'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit, level_id: @habit.current_habit_level.id }), remote: true, method: 'post', data: { modal: true }, class: 'remove-check', id: 'remove_check' %>
<% end %>
```

Where upon clicking `Submit` a POST request is made to the **DaysMissedController**'s create action, which will increment `missed_days` by +1.

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 2
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
```

How can we associate `date_field` entry with each increment of `missed_days`? In other words, for every missed day there should be a missed day date.

This way in addition to showing HOW MANY DAYS A USER MISSED we would show WHAT DAYS A USER MISSED.

**db**

```
  create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "missed_days",  default: 0
    t.boolean  "conceal",      default: false
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.datetime "date_started"
    t.string   "trigger"
    t.string   "action"
    t.string   "target"
    t.string   "reward"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                                      null: false
    t.integer  "order"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.text     "committed",    default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
  end

  add_index "habits", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id_and_created_at", using: :btree
  add_index "habits", ["user_id"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "levels", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.integer  "missed_days",   default: 0
    t.datetime "missed_days_date"      # How should we integrate this?
    t.integer  "days_lost",     default: 0
    t.integer  "current_level"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :habits do
    resources :levels do
      # This route increments and decrements missed days
      resources :days_missed, only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
    end
  end
```

Here's the **[gist](http://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on all you want to do with the missed_days info. You could do something hacky like storing all the missed dates as json (or even just as a comma separated string!) and storing them all in your `missed_days_date` column.

The correct way though, in terms of relational database design, would be to have a new `missed_dates` table, which has the following fields: `id`, `date_missed`, `level_id`.

Then, in your rails models, a `Level` `has_many :missed_dates`, and `MissedDate` `belongs_to :level`.

Your `DaysMissedController` would become your `MissedDatesController` and would essentially be a standard CRUD controller that creates new records in your `missed_dates` table. You'll likely want to implement your existing `missed_days` column as a [counter cache column](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

This way is a bit more effort up front, and involves an extra table/model, but it will be the most flexible long term. Eg, later, you may want to find out what a user's reason was for missing each day (eg. lack of time, too lazy, forgot, etc) - and if you go with the hacky solution, this would be very hard. If you go with the correct solution, this would be as simple as adding a new `reason` column to your `missed_dates` table.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me get the ball rolling. I love your suggestion about user reasons. I'll probably implement that in the near future and I'll have you to thank :] How do you think I should convert `<%= link_to 'Submit'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit, level_id: @habit.current_habit_level.id }) %>`? I'm just confused by when you say "your `DaysMissedController` would become your `MissedDatesController`" does that mean I can pretty much copy the create action into the new controller? Thanks again!

Comment: You can - but remember that you've now got to create a new MissedDay record in that action, too. So you'd have to make the modifications to do that.

Comment: Do you have a few minutes to chat Joshua? Struggling with this now. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88433/how-to-associate-missed-days-with-a-date

Comment: I'm at work at the moment. If your project is open source and up somewhere like github I might be able to find time over the next few days to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new model, `MissedDay`, which has a date, and belongs to Level and User (if I understood your model structure correctly). User and Level have many MissedDays.